# How to call the id from text_area with watir-webdriver?

Tags: ruby, watir-webdriver

```
for i in 0..10
  if @b.text_field(:cols  => "40", :index => i).exists?
    id = @b.text_field(:cols  => "40", :index => i)
    if profile_profile_qualifications_attributes_new_(\d)+_comment/.match(id)
      @b.text_field(:cols  => "40", :index => i).set "Rock!"
    end
  end
end
```

The code above fails with

```
Error: can't convert Watir::TextField to String (TypeError)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
id = @b.text_field(:cols  => "40", :index => i).id
```